# Manually disposing a DisposeBag in RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I want to cancel a request and one of the ways is to manually remove the disposable bag.

```
.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

As I have the disposeBag object, is there a good way to cancel the request other than that I mentioned above?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to just change reference to your disposeBag object.
Make it nil or assign new object to disposeBag.

All request will be cancelled.

Answer (score 13):

Another option, besides deallocating a `DisposeBag`, is to use `CompositeDisposable`, which has an explicit `dispose` method.

Comment: will this dispose the new subscription or its just like clear of RxJava?

Comment: CompositeDisposable is the ticket here.

Comment: Note that `CompositeDisposable` does not dispose on deinit. IT IS NOT A REPLACEMENT FOR A `DisposeBag`. You should still add your `CompositeDisposable` to another `DisposeBag` or make sure you manually dispose of it on your deinit method.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to reinitialise the dispose bag reference:

`disposeBag = .init()`