# How to unsubscribe from Observable in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to unsubscribe from Observable in RxSwift. In order to do this I used to set Disposable to nil. But it seems to me that after updating to RxSwift 3.0.0-beta.2 this trick does not work and I can not unsubscribe from Observable:

```
//This is what I used to do when I wanted to unsubscribe
var cancellableDisposeBag: DisposeBag?

func setDisposable(){
    cancellableDisposeBag = DisposeBag()
}

func cancelDisposable(){
    cancellableDisposeBag = nil
}
```

So may be somebody can help me how to unsubscribe from Observable correctly?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969328/manually-disposing-a-disposebag-in-rxswift

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#disposing.  What you mention sounds like a bug.  Maybe better to report it as an issue at https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues

Answer (score 28):

In general it is good practice to out all of your subscriptions in a DisposeBag so when your object that contains your subscriptions is deallocated they are too.

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

func setupRX() {
   button.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext : { _ in 
      print("Hola mundo")
   }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

but if you have a subscription you want to kill before hand you simply call dispose() on it when you want too

like this:

```
let disposable = button.rx.tap.subcribe(onNext : {_ in 
   print("Hallo World")
})
```

Anytime you can call this method and unsubscribe.

```
disposable.dispose()
```

But be aware when you do it like this that it your responsibility to get it deallocated.

Comment: Can't you do both? (Add it to a dispose bag in case it doesn't get deallocated and also potentially dispose of it inside the block depending on the logic)

Comment: As @shim suggests, I do both: I store a reference to the Disposable so that I can later call dispose() on it manually (thus effectively cancelling the subscription), but I also call .dispose(by: _disposeBag) when I create the subscription.

Comment: @Daniel How can apply your solution to a `BehaviorRelay`

Answer (score 9):

Follow up with answer to Shim's question

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
var subscription: Disposable?

func setupRX() {
    subscription = button.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext : { _ in 
        print("Hola mundo")
    })
}
```

You can still call this method later

```
subscription?.dispose()
```

Comment: If you have Disposable saved already in `subscription`, there is no need to add it to `disposeBag`.