# RxSwift - Stop duplicate subscribes to an observer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I'm subscribing an UITableViewCell to an Observer in order to handle changes to that cell (I'm currently doing this at:

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Problem I have is as the cell on any kind of reload is then re-subscribed and anytime I do an "onNext" the observer is fired multiple times.

Is there anyway to stop a particular Observer from being subscribed multiple times?

I've attempted to keep a list of Cells that have been subscribed and stop them from re-subscribing - but this seems to cause other issues further down the line (and doesn't feel like the right solution)

Comment: I think u need to first  unsubscribe and then subscribe in tableView method

Comment: Have you tried to clean your DisposeBag? Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996937/how-to-unsubscribe-from-observable-in-rxswift)

Answer (score 5):

Create a DisposeBag in your cell, then attach your `subscribe` event on it.

Reset the `bag` in the `prepareForReuse`.

You can also add a `debug()` call bedfore the subscribe to check if `onComplete` is properly called